# how to get the async pipe working with rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, rxjs

I need help, since the else loading of my async pipe does not trigger, even though the data load works correctly, the loading template never triggers when subscribing, I have a BehaviorSubject in my service.
If anyone help me with any solution I would appreciate it too much as I have tried a lot of things and could not reach the expected result.
My expected result is that when choosing a date, it triggers the subscription and while it subscribes the loading is triggered, if the length is greater than 0 the table is loaded, if not, it shows the template that there are no items.
Thank you very much in advance.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

BehaviourSubject() is an observable, so you will need to subscribe to your data source before setting your subject to the result of your observable. Without a subscription there will be no result!

Try the following in your test (if list is an observable in your api service):

```
this.apiAgenda().list.subscribe(res => 
{
  this.list$.next(res); 
});
```

Comment: Hello friend, I have the subscription with the .next () in the same service that returns the data: / so it is not the solution

Comment: Can I suggest you move the subscribe() into your UI component. The list$ is an asynchronous observable which will work only when you call next() to stream the list to the corresponding value of your list$ observable in your UI component.